# USB to I2C for a beginner

Tags: usb, i2c, ftdi

I recently ordered and [CJMCU-200 FT200XD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076BBX5DH) a USB to I2C and I am trying to read information from a [BME280](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Adafruit/2652?qs=sGAEpiMZZMu8c2wsui%252biYgTVaxGoqHBLC1cp0p8Yqcw%3D) using it's I2C output. I am new to FTDI and am having some trouble finding information on how to setup such a device. I plan to write a program the would read in the serial data. My question is did I get the right kind of USB to I2C chip? I have been reading other questions and the problem half the time is the wrong chip.

Comment: There are cloned FTDI chips around that don't work properly with official drivers.

Comment: I have installed the drivers and the suggested program to interface but I don't get consistent results. I am guessing that I am missing something.

Comment: @MichaelH. You'll need an oscilloscope and look at the lines, you should at least be able to send commands and 'toggle' the lines. Make sure you have pull ups

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. What is needed is a USB chip than can act as a I2C master. FT200XD is a I2C slave chip, so it cannot be used as a master to talk to another I2C slave like the BME280 in the question.

Comment: +1 good point, the datasheet says, on p.12, "The FT200XD device only operates as a slave,"

Comment: Yeah I caught the slave thing a bit to late. Thank you for the information.

Comment: How can it act as a slave since it has a virtual console? It can clearly send commands as a master otherwise it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @Alexis You can read the data sheet yourself. The chip is an I2C slave. And the chip provides a virtual serial console to a host (PC) as a USB device chip. These are not mutually exclusive properties in any way. And of course it makes sense. The MCU, as an I2C master, can through the I2C slave chip, write data to PC and read data from PC, when the MCU has free time to handle communication through the chip.

Comment: Do you mean it's gonna accept all the transactions? How about a read? I2C expects a result right after the ACK... unless it does clock stretching for milliseconds.

Comment: @Alexis The chip operation is not a mystery that needs guessing in the comment section of a different question, this is not the place for that discussion. If you want to know how it works, read the datasheet, or ask a question about it.